# Why does Node.js's ICMP listen get two responses when I ping localhost?

Tags: networking, ping, node.js, icmp

I am currently using the [ICMP NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icmp) for developing a custom contribution node for [node-red](https://www.nodered.org).
After a couple of days' testing and making sure everything is okay before publishing I stumbled upon weird results when pinging localhost while ICMP listen is active...

I run `ping -c 1 127.0.0.1` which makes sure only one message is sent, and I get these results:

```
{
  icmp: {
received: 84,
source: '127.0.0.1',
time: 1585757577079,
message: `���^�(\u0001\u0000\b\t\n\u000b\f\r\u000e\u000f\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a\u001b\u001c\u001d\u001e\u001f !"#$%&'()*+,-./01234567`,
type: 'Received!'
 },
_msgid: '55682271.0e325c'
}

{   
icmp: {
received: 84,
source: '127.0.0.1',
time: 1585757577107,
message: `���^�(\u0001\u0000\b\t\n\u000b\f\r\u000e\u000f\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a\u001b\u001c\u001d\u001e\u001f !"#$%&'()*+,-./01234567`,
type: 'Received!'
},
_msgid: '4cd1b4b1.729c9c'
}
```

So as we can see here we have two exactly the same messages from the same source. The only difference is the timestamp of both messages.

So my question is:
What is the second message?
Is that the response that was sent back to the ping command?
Is there any name for this behavior?

Here are the results of the ping:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping -c 1 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.193 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.193/0.193/0.193/0.000 ms
```

Comment: This issue is almost certainly specific to Node.js and the libraries/modules/packages you're using with it. Did it maybe show you both the ICMP Echo Request and the ICMP Echo Response?

Comment: No, this is all of the data I can get from the ICMP package as icmp.listen only return buffer and source address.

Comment: I suspect your ICMP listener is listening to all ICMP messages either sent or received, so you're seeing both the ping request and the ping reply.

Comment: This issue only occurs when I ping from the localhost when I ping from the remote machine I only get one message.
I think this is a natural thing.

Comment: When you ping 127.0.0.1, the destination address of both the request and the reply is 127.0.0.1. So if you're filtering on "ICMPs to any destination address owned by this host", pinging localhost will show you both the request and response, whereas pinging that host's LAN IP address from another host would only show the request.